# jdbc without localhost program?

Tags: jdbc, hsqldb

I want to make a local disc **JDBC** but not related to local host and want the program to be independent so that the user of the program doesn't need to setup a localhost like xamp, etc.

I want a local disc and I found that **HSQSLDB** does this but while following a certain tutorial, I found that I need to create/use these files

- `file.scripts`
- `file.properties`

**I don't know how to get this type of db.**

I know `file.sql`.

Eventually, I need your help to proceed with making a db connection related to a db file rather than a host, to let all people use my program without having a local host program.

Please guide me with an example of database setup and also kindly provide a connection string example to know how to connect.

Sorry for the long talk i am just confused.

Comment: Your terminology doesn't make much sense. It looks like you're looking for an *embedded* database. That's what you should use when googling for a solution. HSQLDB can indeed be run in embedded (in-process) mode, instead of talking to a database server. See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_inprocess

Comment: i did what the link said and it bugs :((
http://imgur.com/L8DISSy

Comment: "if the file: database name is "testdb" and its files are located in the same directory"
what files are with the the testdb.sql ???
i have only for example testdb.sql and i don't know where to get other files

Comment: and when i try 
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:hsqldb:data/explorecalifornia", "SA", "");
it creates some files in the project folder and don't really acces my db it creates an empty one

Comment: You shouldn't care about what the file contains, and shouldn't try to create these files by yourself. Let HSQLDB create an empty database files for for you, and use SQL to create tables and data inside it.

Comment: Are you saying that you have an .sql file containing information that was exported from some other existing database and you want to access that information from your Java application using HSQLDB?